# How to construct an axis resulting from a subtraction of two values with matplotlib?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

From a json file, I retrieve two dates from two distinct fields: `endDate` and `startDate`.

I would like to plot on the `y` axis the difference between these two dates based on another value contained in the json file.

With `matplotlib` is it possible to calculate the difference between these two dates with code that would look like:

```
y_axis_date_difference = [i["endDate"]-i["startDate"] for i in data]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Not really sure why matplotlib should be doing any 'calculations'. Prepare your data and then pass it to the appropriate plotting method. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you want to add a new column to your dataframe, "duration" where this difference is stored?  This is more a pandas/numpy thing. Matplotlib (or Seaborn) can then visualize that data.  Your description is too vague to know what kind of plot you're after.